# My downloadable product page showing html source only

Tags: magento-1.9, renderer

I have installed theme  http://themeforest.net/item/hosoren-responsive-magento-fashion-theme/12784020

It's working fine. But when I click on `My Downloadable Products` link from my account section, it showing `html source`.

URL: http://127.0.0.1/xyz.com/downloadable/customer/products showing page source only.

Can anybody help me to find solution please ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pleased to share you, How I fixed this issue.

After debug a lots, I found that one minor mistake in magento base design file.

File path is : `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/downloadable/customer/products/list.phtml #60`

Code snippets

```
<td><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getPurchased()->getProductName()) ?> - <a href="<?php echo $this->getDownloadUrl($_item) ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('downloadable'))->__('Start Download') ?>" <?php echo $this->getIsOpenInNewWindow()?'onclick="this.target=\'_blank\'"':''; ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_item->getLinkTitle()); ?></a></td>
```

Change

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('downloadable'))->__('Start Download') ?>
```

replace with

```
<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('Start Download')) ?>
```

Comment: This issue has been fixed in RWD theme.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a server issue, I assume a wrong `mime type` or `attachment`.

You probably have some webserver rule based on the word **downloadable** coming from your URL.

Comment: Thank for answer. But in this case other URLs are working except mentioned URL. I found the bugs in core design file and I posted the fixes here below.